# What is difference between parenthesis and bracket in Numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Could somebody explain the difference between () and [] operations in Numpy?

For example, I have run the following codes:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array(([2, 9], [1, 5], [3, 6]), dtype=float)
print(x1)
print(type(x1))
x2 = np.array([[2, 9], [1, 5], [3, 6]], dtype=float)
print(x2)
print(type(x2))

y1 = np.array(([2, 9]), dtype=float)
print(y1)
print(type(y1))

y2 = np.array([[2, 9]], dtype=float)
print(y2)
print(type(y2))
```

Both x1 and x2 have the same data and type, but y1 and y2 are different.
I think that y1 and y2 should be same. Could some one explain the reason why y1 and y2 are different ?

Comment: [] instantiates a list. () Instantiates a tuple. Reading the docs about those should help.

Comment: `y1 = np.array(([2, 9]), dtype=float)` is equivalent to `y1 = np.array([2, 9], dtype=float)` - a flat structure. In other words, it's a single list wrapped in parentheses. In the longer case, `x1 = np.array(([2, 9], [1, 5], [3, 6]), dtype=float)` is a tuple of lists (a nested structure) because the parentheses now contain more than 1 item, separated by commas. This is standard to Python, not Numpy

Comment: @DavidCulbreth: No, parentheses do not construct a tuple, they're always just a grouping construct. The comma operator constructs a tuple. So `(_)` isn't a tuple, no matter what `_` is, but `(_, _)` is a tuple, or even `(_ ,)` is a tuple.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!. Now, I understand. the tuple is constructed by , rather than (). quite interesting.

Comment: See python docs on tuples - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Answer (score 1):

Arrays `y1` and `y2` have different shapes. First one is one-dimensional, the second one is 2-dimensional. Parentheses around `[2, 9]` have no meaning (because there is only one element inside it and comma). See below and the first comment as well.

```
y1 = np.array(([2, 9]), dtype=float)
y1.shape  # (2,)
y2 = np.array([[2, 9]], dtype=float)
y2.shape  # (1, 2)
```

Something about parentheses:

```
a = (3)
type(a)  # int
b = (3, )
type(b)  # tuple
c = (3, 4)
type(c)  # tuple
```

Comment: And your edit about parentheses is incorrect. `b = 3,` is also a tuple and there are no parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Numpy actually.

This:

```
([2, 9], [1, 5], [3, 6])
```

is a tuple of 3 lists.

This:

```
[[2, 9], [1, 5], [3, 6]]
```

is a list of 3 lists.

Since tuples and lists are both ordered sequences, numpy treat them the same.

Now this:

```
([2, 9])
```

is actually a list of two integers - the parens only force evaluation order of the expression - so what numpy gets is really

```
[2, 9]
```

while this:

```
[[2, 9]]
```

is a list of one list (of two integers). So of course numpy won't treat them the same since they really are different.

The point here is that what makes a tuple is not the parens but the coma, so the first example:

```
([2, 9], [1, 5], [3, 6])
```

is really:

```
[2, 9], [1, 5], [3, 6]
```

TL;DR:

for the third example, you want:

```
([2, 9],)
```

not

```
([2, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

That additional bracket doesn't make any change. It is effectively `[2,9]`.

There is also another example you can look :

```
np.random.randn((((((((((((((((((((((1))))))))))))))))))))))
```

It is effectively :

```
np.random.randn(1)
```

This is not the speciality of Numpy. Additional parentheses can be added almost anywhere as long as it contain single expression.

In contrast if Python find any **comma-seperated value inside a parentheses or empty parentheses**  then it will try to convert to tuple object.

Answer (score 1):

to my understanding, entering a tuple is in np.array is also termed as a list, for example

> a=np.zeros((3,3))
>
> array([[0., 0., 0.],
>          [0., 0., 0.],
>          [0., 0., 0.]])

same as if we input a list in np.array for zero's initialization

> a=np.zeros([3,3])
>
> array([[0., 0., 0.],
>          [0., 0., 0.],
>          [0., 0., 0.]])

but if you initialize using the same pattern in simple python it will count them as tuple and list respectively.

> a=([2,6],[4,5])
>
> ([2, 6], [4, 5])
>
> class 'tuple'
>
> b=[[2,6],[4,5]]
>
> type(b)
>
> class 'list'